# Sqoop import data to hive and hdfs

Tags: mysql, hive, hdfs, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

Can we import data with sqoop into hdfs and hive?
I have try it with two different user (root and admin)
Below the command between root and admin

[Root]

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://10.6.162.58/test_alpha --username pbd -P --table posts --hive-import --hive-database test_root --hive-table posts1 --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --target-dir test_hive_root/2
```

[Admin]

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://10.6.162.58/test_alpha --username pbd -P --table posts --hive-import --hive-database test_admin --hive-table posts1 --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --target-dir test_hive_admin/2
```

It returns:

Both ways successful import data to hive but both fail import to HDFS.

For root, it don't create directory that I've defined "test_hive_root/2"

For admin, it's just create directory "test_hive_admin/2" but only "success" file that have been created not the data (usually when I import it to HDFS, it will create "success" file and 4 more file)

How I can solve this problem?
Can sqoop import to HDFS and Hive?

Comment: How do you 'import to HDFS' ? Hive table is nothing more than Table created with HDFS location. I you created HDFS files you should always be able to read them using Hive table if location is the same HDFS where you loaded files

Comment: This how I import to HDFS using user root " sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://10.6.162.58/test_alpha --username pbd -P --table posts --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --target-dir test_hive_root/2 "

Comment: Or if using user admin "sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://10.6.162.58/test_alpha --username pbd -P --table posts --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --target-dir test_hive_admin/2"

Comment: If I import to HDFS , I can track where the files imported to hdfs but when I import to Hive (using --hive-import) I can't track where the files imported in hdfs. In target-dir, there is only _success file

Comment: and is target dir the same as table location?

Comment: I can't locate the table location whether I access with root or admin (via ssh cmd) or admin in ambari files view. And there aren't any folder called /user/hive/warehouse

Comment: If I open /user/hive in ambari there are only 3 folder (.Trash, .hiveJars, .sparkStaging) and in ssh there are only (5 folder) .cache, .config, .mozilla, .oracle_jre_usage, .ssh  and (3 files) .bash_history, .bash_logout, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .hivehistory

Comment: now I've found the hive warehouse is located, it's in apps/hive/warehouse

Comment: Congratulations! Now the question can be closed

Comment: but I still wonder why --target-dir and _success file is still created when --hive-import is executed? why not the hive table is located at --target-dir?

Comment: The answer is here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/198586/running-a-sqoop-job-with-a-target-dir-destination.html

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target-dir`  controls where the data needs to store temporarily before loading into Hive table, but doesn't create hive table in that location.

Table is created in the directory specified in `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property in the `hive-site.xml`.

If you want to import to specific directory then use `target-dir` without `hive-import` argument and create hive table on top of HDFS directory.

(or)

Create Hive external table pointing to your target-dir then in sqoop import remove --create-hive-table argument and --target-dir.

Read the answer here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/198586/running-a-sqoop-job-with-a-target-dir-destination.html

And here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/193934/sqoop-import-mssql-table-into-hdfs.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope you used the `/` prefix when giving the path for `--target-dir`

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://10.6.162.58/test_alpha --username pbd -P --table posts --hive-import --hive-database test_root --hive-table posts1 --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --target-dir /test_hive_root/2
```